# Which is correct: "methods of ID check" or "methods of ID checking"?

Tags: suffixes

I'm writing some text that explains three different ways of carrying out an ID check. Would the section heading read "Methods of ID check" or "Methods of ID checking"?

If someone could explain the reasoning behind the answer that would be great. For some reason I can't get my head around this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Methods of checking ID" is more idiomatic.

Comment: It depends on if you're referring to an object or event, or if you're referring to an activity. Thinking of it in plural terms might help. Do you want to talk about people who go through two different checks, or do you want to talk about the checking process itself? It's likely that the first comment here is what you're aiming for. If you're thinking of the *process* rather than the *event*, then you probably want to use *checking*, and use it as a single-word verb. But if you're describing different types of events (such as gate mechanisms), then you probably want to use *check* as a noun.

Comment: In other words, is the focus on the security guards (*checking*) or is it on the security mechanisms (*checks*)?